# Are there words to describe "smell concepts"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For visual impressions, we have a rich vocabulary to describe concepts without using concrete objects:

- Color: blue, red, green, bright, dark. Combinations of those.
- Shapes: Round, pointy, straight, curved, concave, convex, flat, rough, ...
- Textures: Striped, dotted, dashed, ...

For auditory impressions I can also name a few:

- Volume: Loud, silent
- Frequency: low, high

For gustatory sensations I would say concepts are:

- Salty
- Bitter
- Sour
- Sweet
- Umami

The tactile concepts are similar to the visual ones:

- Shapes: See above
- Roughness
- Elasticity

Now to my question: Of course, I can say something smells like a flower, like grass, like excrements, like grilling, wet dog, ....

But those are only analogies. And quite vague ones, too. So for example, if I wanted to describe somebody the smell of a specific type of wood, I would have no idea how to do so. Is this only my fault / problem (so: do I simply lack the words, but there are some) or is this a broader phenomenon (and thus could be asked on https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: You could try reading descriptions on wine bottles. they generally have taste, texture and aroma on them.

Comment: What is texture of wine? What is the difference between taste and aroma?

Comment: Ask the sommeliers round here! 'Compare for example the silky tannins of a red Burgundy wine to the grippy, almost astringent tannins of a young Barolo wine...', 'tannin in red wine is a major contributor to texture.', 'Alcohol adds viscosity to a wine.' etc. Google `wine texture`, there's loads of things

Comment: There are many comparators used, but people often disagree over what a certain smell is redolent of, and the comparators are usually given in a form such as 'This meadowsweet smells like the disinfectant they used in hospitals in the 50s'. A list parallelling 'salty / bitter ...' is probably not available and would be too peripheral (as non-standard) for ELU at this time.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has an article on "Odor" [Odor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odor) (as well as one on Olfaction, but it's about the science, not descriptive vocabulary) including this:

> Different categorizations of primary odors have been proposed, among
> others this, which relies on seven primary odors (with
> examples):[13][14][15]
>
> Musky – perfumes/aftershave
>
> Putrid – rotten eggs
>
> Pungent – vinegar
>
> Camphoraceous – mothballs
>
> Ethereal – dry cleaning fluid
>
> Floral – roses (see also floral scent)
>
> Pepperminty – mint gum
>
> Although recently progress has been made, the idea of primary
> perceptions is disputed, and more so probably the concept of primary
> odors.[15]